# In Rational Functional Tester How to Run 2 scripts together with 2nd script many times

Tags: automated-testing

I have 2 scripts and calling those 2 scripts in the 3rd script like below

```
callScript("LoginScript");

callScript("AddPatient");
```

When I am running the 3rd script. I am getting Specify Playback Options. I am getting Datapool iteration Count as "`1`".

I want to run "`LoginScript`" once and "`AddPatient`" Iterate Until Done.

So there is any way I can have Datapool iteration count in the code as many times I have patient information the excel sheet.